# PHP error printing inside class

Tags: php, class, oop

I'm trying to play with a class and not understand how it works. Some people explained how to pass variables between a function. My problem at the moment is errors. And how to extract errors from the class and print to the screen. My output is `username` only. How to get errors?

```
class form
{
    protected $username;
    protected $password;
    protected $errors = array();

function __construct($username, $password){
    $this->username = $username;
    $this->password = $password;
}
public function get_errors()
{
    return $this->errors;
}

public function getPassword(){
    return $this->password;
}  

public function getUserName() {
    return $this->username;
    return $this->errors = "No MySQL connection.";
}

}

$test = new form('name1', 'passw2');
echo $test->getUserName();
```

Comment: How to get errors? - `echo implode("<br />", $test->getErrors());`

Comment: cannot return two times.

Comment: No inside if logic. Example if username is null then error = 'please set username'. Something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not return two time inside a function. But you can achieve what you want like below:-

```
public function getUserName() {
    $this->errors = "No MySQL connection.";
    return $this->username.'<br/>'.$this->errors;
}
```

Note:- this is the solution but your code have no mean. You have to do some useful stuff

Answer (score 1):

try throw exception

```
public function getUserName() {
   if($this->errors) {
     throw new Exception($this->errors);
   }
   return $this->username;
}

$test = new form('name1', 'passw2');

try {
  echo $test->getUserName();
} catch(Exception $error) {
  echo 'Error:'.$error->getMessage();
}
```

If you get error you can simple catching this error and output to `web`,`console` or `error log`;

Comment: Best answer so far. Why people insist in stumbling uppon problems that were solved back in 2004 (for php) and much earlier by other languages? I feel like most php questions are programming questions and not language specific.

Comment: @SparK thanks, for many people using magic methods, exception, trades and other feature language the bad practic.... I don't understand why? may be easy write just `return; return;return; return;` and forgot write `return` again...

Answer (score 1):

```
class form
{
    protected $username;
    protected $password;
    protected $errors = array();

    function __construct($username, $password){
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->password = $password;
    }
    public function getErrors()
    {
        return $this->errors;
    }

    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }  

    public function getUserName()
    {
        /* Add some an error to an error's array */
        $this->errors[] = "No MySQL connection.";
        return $this->username;
    }
}

$test = new form('name1', 'passw2');
echo $test->getUserName();
var_dump($test->getErrors()); /* Get errors from a class */
```